# Optimal voting algorithm for two-person position

Tags: voting-theory

Say there is an election for a position filled by two people (e.g. two senators), and *n* people are running in the race.

Considering that preferences may vary (e.g. some people might think candidates A and C complement each other well, even though they might believe A and B are the best individuals in the race), what is the best voting algorithm?

The best one I could think of is to have everyone vote for their top two preferences, take the single top winner of the winning pair, and then have everyone vote again for the remaining one... but I'm not sure if there is a better way.

Comment: It seems like that would depend on your assumptions about how the voters would behave and what their payoffs are for each pair of candidates elected.

Comment: @Qudit: I'm not sure what kinds of assumptions I should make and what is reasonable, so feel free to give an answer based on whatever you consider a reasonable assumption...